# Nextcord: Cannot access ffmpeg on server

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I use this code to access to the `ffmpeg.exe` for my discord music bot.

```py
nextcord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename,executable='./database/ffmpeg.exe', **ffmpeg_options)
```

I can run this smoothly without bug in my pc
But when I host my bot on **heroku or epikhost,** I meet this error:

```py
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './database/ffmpeg.exe'
```

How can I fix this error? Any suggestion or answer would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go `heroku dashboard > setting > buildpacks` and add these 2 buildpacks to your app.

- https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
- https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git